# Dajaxice running locally, but django settings problems to make it work online

Tags: django, django-settings, dajaxice

I have created a Django account which uses Dajaxice and Dajax.

I run my website in an azure VM. When I run it with localhost Dajaxice/Dajax work perfectly.

However, online this does not work anymore. I have some configurations problems in my settings, but I am unable to fix it.

Locally, Dajaxice/Dajax is pointed in this way:

```
<script src="/static/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The Dajaxice/Dajax function is called like this:

```
GET http://localhost:1465/dajaxice/chocolate.chocolate.cellphone/?argv=%7B%22cell%22%3A%22jk%22%2C%22pID%22%3A%228353%22%7D
```

How should I change my settings, so I can access dajaxice online?

This is my settings.py so far:

```
from os import path
PROJECT_ROOT = path.dirname(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)))

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ''

HTMLFILES_DIR = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\chocolate\chocolate\chocolate\htmlFiles'

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('x', 'x@gmail.com'),
)

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'xx',
        'ENGINE': 'x',
        'HOST': 'x.x.x',
        'USER': 'x@zx',
        'PASSWORD': 'x!',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'provider': 'x'
        }
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = HTMLFILES_DIR + '\Pictures'

MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:1781/Pictures/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (

    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'dajaxice.finders.DajaxiceFinder',

)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chocolate.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'chocolate.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (

   HTMLFILES_DIR
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chocolate.chocolate',
    'dajaxice',
    'dajax',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin'
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'x@outlook.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'x'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console':{
            'level':'INFO',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'dajaxice':{
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found how to do it. For anyone with few experience in Django, this information could be helpful.

When I use localhost, having the following information is just fine:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

However, once you plan to deploy your application, you need to create a file somewhere in your application and include the path in `STATIC_ROOT`.  In my case, it was the following:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/chocolate/chocolate/chocolate/static/'
```

I manually created the file called **static**, which you can see above. Then, add the name of the file created in `STATIC_URL`.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Afterwards, with your console access the file where you have your app's manage.py . Make sure to have added python as a command and write `python manage.py collectstatic` . All your static files will located there, in the static file you created. In my case, the files of dajaxice and dajax appeared in this folder after having written `python manage.py collectstatic`.

Now, dajaxice/dajax should work online after deployment.